# GraphQL Query returns error .filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, graphql

I am trying to return some data from an API, which is giving me a message error "userAPI.filter is not a function". The project is set up with json server, and i also have a db.js file which has an array of objects. The problem i am having is getting the filter to work with the json server. I have already tested it and i can get the data back from the local .js file with no problems. I can even get the data back from the json server for getting all the users.

It just does not seem to be working when i use the filter at the bottom. I have a feeling it has something to do with the data i get back with axios, possibly the variable not being an array? But it works for getting all the users back. And im pretty sure the filter works properly as it works with the test, userAPI2 array of objects in the file.

```
  const axios = require('axios');

const Query = {
    greeting(parent, args, ctx, info) {
        if(args.name) {
            return `Hello ${args.name}!`
        } else {
            return 'Hello!'
        }
    },
    avengers(parent, args, ctx, info) {
        if(args.name) {
            return `Your favourite character is ${args.name}`
        } else {
            return 'Avengers Assemble!'
        }
    },
    hello(parent, args, ctx, info) {
        return "Hello World"
    },
    me() {
        return {
            id: "abc123",
            name: "John",
            email: "example@gmail.com",
            age: 32
        }
    },
    users(parent, args, {db}, info) {
        // Import from an external API server in this case json-server
        const userAPI = axios.get('http://localhost:3004/users')
        .then(response => {
            return response.data
        })

        if (!args.query) {
            // Import from local .js file
            return db.users 

            // Import from an external API server in this case json-server
            //return userAPI 
        }
            // Import from local .js file
            // return db.users.filter((user) => {
            //     return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(args.query.toLowerCase())
            // })

            const userAPI2 = [
                {
                id: '1',
                name: 'User1',
                email: 'user1@user1.com',
                age: 32,
                },
                {
                id: '2',
                name: 'User2',
                email: 'user2@user2.com',
                age: 32,
                },
                {
                id: '3',
                name: 'User3',
                email: 'user3@user3.com',
                age: 32,
                }
            ]

            // Import from local .js file
            // return db.users.filter((user) => {
            //     return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(args.query.toLowerCase())
            // })

            // Import from an external API server in this case json-server
            return userAPI.filter((user) => {
                return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(args.query.toLowerCase())
            })
    }
}

export {Query as default}
```

Comment: it seems userAPI is not Array! did you tried logging it? and if it's an array, then use `Array.from`

Comment: @MohsenZareZardeyni I just tried logging it again it says "Promise { "pending" }​<state>: "pending"​<prototype>: PromiseProto { … } index.js:30". So now im thinking its because i need to return the response.data and then pass that to the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `userAPI` variable contains the return value of the call to `axios.get`. Axios request methods (like `request`, `get`, `post`, etc.) return a Promise that will resolve to a response object. It's that response object itself that contains the `data`, which in this case will be an array.

If you want to `filter` the data, you must do so within the Promise chain returned by the resolver, for example:

```
users(parent, args, {db}, info) {
  return axios.get('http://localhost:3004/users')
    .then(response => {
      if (!args.query) {
        return response.data  
      }
      return response.data.filter((user) => {
        return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(args.query.toLowerCase())
      })
    })
}
```

Or using async/await:

```
users: async (parent, args, {db}, info) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:3004/users')
  if (!args.query) {
    return data  
  }
  return data.filter((user) => {
    return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(args.query.toLowerCase())
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks much appreciated the code worked. I figured it was caused by promises and axios.

Comment: Just one more thing. The code for using Promises works fine. However the code for using async/await throws an error. `await is a reserved word`

Comment: Did you include the `async` keyword?

Comment: Oh sorry my bad i copied the code inside the function and missed the `async` keyword... Its all working thanks again!